# Error writing headers when returning FileInfo HttpResult

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm on Mono 3.x, on Mac OSX and I'm trying to return  a static file with ServiceStack. The code is (and should be, according to other answers) very straightforward:

```
public class AirPlayService : Service
{
    public object Get(Movie request)
    {
        var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Movies", request.Name);

        var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
        return new HttpResult(file, asAttachment:false); 
    }
}
```

The Movie object is a simple DTO.
When my Get() gets called I see the following error in my Terminal window:

> ERROR: Error occured while Processing Request: [IOException] Write failure, Exception: Write failure
>   INFO: Failed to write error to response: {0}, Exception: Cannot be changed after headers are sent.
>   ERROR: Error in HttpListenerResponseWrapper: Write failure, Exception: Write failure

ServiceStack is version 3.9.35; Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.3 (master/39c48d5 Tue Jan  8 12:12:24 EST 2013); .NET 4.5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to be solved with the latest version of MonoDevelop (now using Xamarin Studio) and ServiceStack (3.9.38).

Comment: Can you add the solution you found as an answer? This will help future users find the answer faster and you earn more reputation.

Comment: @Brent great edit, hunting for badges?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem on my dad's computer, it worked for me by using :

```
public class AirPlayService : Service
{
    public object Get(Movie request)
    {
        var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), ( "Movies", request.Name);

        var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
        return new HttpResult(file, asAttachment:false);
```

Comment: Hi ValterZHD, I don't see the difference with my code, except for an extra parenthesis that makes the compiler complain.